# Telethon and messages not received from some channels

Tags: python, telethon

I have a software which monitors multiple telegram channels and performs actions based on the received messages.
The problem is that in the past month it stopped received messages from some of the channels.

I'm using one of the examples in the official repositories with some additions.

```
@callback
async def check_chat(self, event=None):
    """
    Checks the input chat where to send and listen messages from.
    """
    if self.me is None:
        return  # Not logged in yet

    chat = self.chat.get().strip()
    try:
        chat = int(chat)
    except ValueError:
        pass
      
        
async def on_msg_received(self, event): 
    global folders_list
    
    now = datetime.now()
    hour = now.hour
    minute = now.minute
                
    nome_chat = ''
    try:
        async for dialog in self.cl.iter_dialogs():
            if(dialog.id == event.chat_id):
                nome_chat = dialog.name
    except:
        logging.warning('error at on_msg_received')

    logging.warning('------- chat = %s', nome_chat)
    testo = event.raw_text
```

With some chats I don't get any activity at all, I expect to get either an error or the chat name.
What could be the issue here?
Does it make any difference if the channel is sending messages from telegram web or desktop?

Comment: Are you sure you're still in those channels?

Comment: @Lonami yes 100% sure. I see the messages from those channels on my telegram app, but nothing here. it's like if they have not sent anything

Comment: Are the channels very large with a lot of activity, or are there too many sessions open for the same user? That also affects.

Comment: @Lonami the channels which have this problem send let's say 1 message every hour, so not a big load of messages. I have some channels which send messages continuously and they are received without any problem.. what do you mean with "sessions"?

Comment: I've just encountered the same problem. Did you ever figure out what was wrong?

Comment: no, I didn't solve the problem. My only guess is that the channels which don't work have some kind of protection against copy/forwarding or something similar. I'm not sure how they achieve so, but that's it

Comment: Same issue here. I don't think it's some protection, Telegram had to change something with the November 2021 update. Now it seems that Telethon is not able to receive new messages from channels with a huge amount of subscribers. @Lonami, do you think is it possible?

Comment: @GiulioBider I had this problem long before the big telegram security update. Anyway I reached out to one of the channels and they said yes, we put some kind of protection to avoid copy (but they did not specify what protection)